# Is there a way to output variables in PHP using isset()?

Tags: php, output

I am trying to visualise variables in PHP using isset(), when I am not using it, a notice comes out saying that the index is undefined.

I am trying to output variables in the tabled using the aforementioned function, but with it, the tables do not output any values.

```
[

<?php
                        // Include config file
                        require_once "config.php";

                        // Attempt select query execution
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM courses";
                        if($result = $pdo->query($sql)){
                            if($result->rowCount() > 0){
                                echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                                    echo "<thead>";
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<th>#</th>";
                                            echo "<th>Enquiry ID</th>";
                                            echo "<th>Course Name</th>";
                                            echo "<th>Course Level</th>";
                                            echo "<th>Action</th>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                    echo "</thead>";
                                    echo "<tbody>";
                                    while($row = $result->fetch()){
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<td>" . isset($row\['courseid'\]) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . isset($row\['enquiryid'\]) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . isset($row\['coursename'\]) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . isset($row\['courselevel'\]) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>";
                                                echo "<a href='read.php?id=". isset($row\['courseid'\]) ."' title='View Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a>";
                                                echo "<a href='update.php?id=". isset($row\['courseid'\]) ."' title='Update Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>";
                                                echo "<a href='delete.php?id=". isset($row\['courseid'\]) ."' title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";
                                            echo "</td>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</tbody>";                            
                                echo "</table>";
                                // Free result set
                                unset($result);
                            } else{
                                echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
                            }
                        } else{
                            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $mysqli->error;
                        }

                        // Close connection
                        unset($pdo);
                        ?>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBMpn.png)

I expect the output of the values included in the database tables, but the fields still continue blank.

Comment: Several things are weird here. First, you shouldn't need `isset` here - even a null value in one of these columns will still be *set*. If you're getting `isset`, you're using column names that don't exist in the database. Second, you're escaping weirdly - `$row\['courseid'\]` should just be `$row['courseid']`. Third, you can't echo the result of `isset`.

Comment: Is this the actual code? What you've shared can't possibly run. It should be throwing: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR), expecting ')'"

Answer (score 3):

`isset()` returns true or false. You can't echo it out directly. You need a conditional that uses `isset()` to check a variable and display it when true.

On the assumption you're running PHP 7, you can use the null coalescing operator. This acts as a shorthand for a ternary that either results in the variable or a blank string depending on whether the variable is set:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['courseid'] ?? '' . "</td>";
```

Documentation: https://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

This is the equivalent of:

```
echo "<td>" . isset($row['courseid']) ? $row['courseid'] : '' . "</td>";
```

If you were forced to use that ternary method however, I'd probably wrap it in a function for convenience.

Comment: Of course, the root cause of the original question is that we're fetching results from a straight `SELECT * FROM tablename` query where we aren't sure of what column names it might contain. That's a very strange situation, to say the least. How is it possible that the definition of table `courses` changes dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

This `isset()` Function Returns True/False, So you can not `echo` out the value directly.

So it's better to use single line condition with `isset()`

**Like i've written below**

`echo "<td>" . isset($row['courseid']) ? $row['courseid'] : 'Not Set' . "</td>";`

Answer (score -1):

I rewrote your while loop as an example:

```
 while($row = $result->fetch()){
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    if (isset($row['courseid'])){
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['courseid']) . "</td>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<td>" . 'NOT SET' . "</td>";
                                    } 

                                    if (isset($row['enquiryid'])){
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['enquiryid'] . "</td>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<td>" . 'NOT SET' . "</td>";
                                    }

                                    if (isset($row['coursename'])){
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['coursename']. "</td>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<td>" . 'NOT SET' . "</td>";
                                    }

                                    if (isset($row['courselevel'])){
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['courselevel']) . "</td>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<td>" . 'NOT SET' . "</td>";
                                    }

                                        echo "<td>";
                                            echo "<a href='read.php?id=". $row['courseid'] ."' title='View Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<a href='update.php?id=". $row['courseid'] ."' title='Update Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<a href='delete.php?id=". $row\'courseid'] ."' title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";
                                        echo "</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
```

Hope that helps